# How do you call a parent directive controller from a child controller (not link method)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I would like to access my parent directive from within my child.

I know that if you use the require property, then the link method has the parent controller passed as a parameter, but how can i access this controller from within my childs controller method.

Here is a plunk of a basic example

http://plnkr.co/edit/wVSurxx7GsRw1EtVdOP1

```
// how can i call this init function??
this.init = function(elem, parentCtrl) {
    $scope.$element = elem;
    parentController = parentCtrl;
}
```

As this shows, i would like to be able to call myChildController init() function...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child's link function will require both controllers, its own and its parent's. The child controller could have a `setParent()` method, used to set the parent controller. A demo:

```
app.directive("child", function() {
    return {
        ...
        require: ["^parent", "child"],
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrls) {
            var parentController = ctrls[0],
                childController = ctrls[1];

            childController.setParent(parentController);
        },
        controller: ["$scope", function($scope) {
            var parentController;

            this.setParent = function(parent) {
                parentController = parent;
            };

            // use parentController...
        }]
    };
});
```

In any case the `require` and the link function are the way to go.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! works perfectly.  I didnt realise you could pass in multiple require parameters, and that would then give you an array of controllers to the link function. Thanks again